# add DB query to $data array, then iterate over it in other file WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function.php file in my plugin I am making and I want a function that gets all data from a table in the DB then stores it in a $data array. My problem is when I call the function outside the functions file the array is null, if I dump the data array out inside the function and then call the function the data is present so I know the query is successful. Here is my code:

functions.php

```
    function getCategories() {

    $data = array();

    global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `metal_work_categories` WHERE 1", ARRAY_N);

    }
```

index.php

```
include('functions.php');

getCategories();
var_dump($data);
```

I also tried initializing the data array in the index.php file and passing it to the function, just a wild stab in the dark really, to no avail:

```
$data = array();
getCategories($data);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how variable scope works. You need to return the data you want from the function, and assign it to a variable.

```
function getCategories() {
   global $wpdb;
   return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `metal_work_categories` WHERE 1", ARRAY_N);
}

$data = getCategories();
```

PS: Next up, stop using global!

Comment: why stop using global?